# Sveltekit window event listener

Tags: window, event-listener, sveltekit

I have this code in vanilla js:

```js
window.addEventListener("message", function (event) { /* my code */ })
```

When I want to add the event listener to my sveltekit app it doesn't work.
I use this to set up the event listener is svelte

```html
<svelte:window on:message={handleMessage} />
```

In the `handleMessage` function I then wait to for the event data, but it never gets there.
Any suggestions what could be wrong?

Comment: Is the `window` in the JS case actually the top-level window?